# How to define the address in the endpoint for hirarchical relationship of classes in wcf?

Tags: .net, wcf

```
    class MyCalculator : IScientificCalculator
    {
         public int Add(int arg1,int arg2)
         {
             return arg1 + arg2;
         }

         public int Multiply(int arg1,int arg2)
         {
            return arg1 * arg2;
         }
    }
```

In the given hierarchy if i have the relation ship parent1:child1-->child1:child2-->child2:child3 
how to define the address? Whether to define the address for each class in the endpoint?

But at the last derived class have all the operation contracts which are in the base class because of Inheritance. Can I define only the address for the base class?
like

```
<service name = "MyCalculator">
<endpoint
address = "http://localhost:8001/MyCalculator/"
binding = "basicHttpBinding"
contract = "IScientificCalculator"
/>
</service>
```

Comment: *In the given hierarchy...* - what hierarchy? I can only see a single level here.

Comment: parent1:child1-->child1:child2-->child2:child3 Like the above example. I am assuming all these parent1,child1,child2,child3 as classes.

Comment: The above example there is a single class called MyCalculator. Are you saying you want to create classes derived from this? Or you want MyCalculator itself to derive from something?

Comment: what is the best approach for defining the address in the endpoint?  defining the address only for the base class because it have all the operation contracts. Or i have to define the endpoints address for each base class? This is my qyuestion

Comment: There is a one to one relationship between a service contract, a service binding, and an address. Base classes do not come into it. I still do not understand what you are asking. Your code example does not demonstrate the question you are asking. Please demonstrate the problem you are facing with a code example, or explain exactly what it is you want to know in the question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What i was looking for

```
[ServiceContract]
interface ISimpleCalculator
{
  [OperationContract]
   int Add(int arg1,int arg2);
}
   [ServiceContract]
  interface IScientificCalculator : ISimpleCalculator
  {
    [OperationContract]
     int Multiply(int arg1,int arg2);
}
```

When it comes to implementing a contract hierarchy, a single service class can implement
the entire hierarchy, just as with classic C# programming:

```
class MyCalculator : IScientificCalculator
{
public int Add(int arg1,int arg2)
{
return arg1 + arg2;
}
public int Multiply(int arg1,int arg2)
{
return arg1 * arg2;
}
}
```

The host can expose a single endpoint for the bottommost interface in the hierarchy:

```
<service name = "MyCalculator">
<endpoint
address = "http://localhost:8001/MyCalculator/"
binding = "basicHttpBinding"
contract = "IScientificCalculator"
/>
</service>
```